# I have a scenario to run a test1 from my current test called test2 in java selenium

Tags: selenium, testng

Below are my requirements. How can I do that in Java Selenium. Please share your suggestions.

Step 1:  Get a count from "GetInfo" tab

Step 2: Then Run another test1 from current test(test2). [The test 1 is another class
   how can i run this class]

Step 3: After  the completion of test1 again I need to get the count from "getInfo" tab.

Step 4: Then I have   to compare the "GetInfo" details

We are using TestNG, maven in our project. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a Selenium problem, this is a pure Java problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I created a method in my test1(where i can have all my logic) , and created an instance of test1 class and calling that method from  my test2.

Comment: You should seriously consider reading through at least the [tour] in order to get most benefit from SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with Selenium or TestNG or even Java. You need to be able to step away and look at your problem. This is just a problem in structuring your logic correctly.

Extract all your logic into a new (helper) class, something like:

```
public class GetInfoLogic {

    public int count() {

        int count = 0;
        // get the count
        return count;
    }

    public void test1_logic() {

        // whatever is the logic for test1

        // maybe this returns some stuff?
    }
}
```

And your two test classes will look like this:

```
public class TestOne {

    @Test
    public void test1() {

        GetInfoLogic getInfo = new GetInfoLogic();
        getInfo.test1_logic();
        // maybe do something with the returned "stuff"
    }
}

public class TestTwo {

    @Test
    public void test2() {

        GetInfoLogic getInfo = new GetInfoLogic();
        int count_before = getInfo.count();
        getInfo.test1_logic();
        int count_after = getInfo.count();

        // compare the "GetInfo" details, maybe something like:
        Assert.assertEquals(count_before, count_after);
    }
}
```

Directly calling one test from another is always a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you are taking the initial value from `GetInfo` tab .Then from your test2 you want to call `test1` which again does some processing and updates the value of the `GetInfo`. Finally you want to compare the value of `GetInfo` details.

As far as i know you can't call a test from within another test. However I do have a work around. You need to merge the task which you are doing in the `test1` into your `test2` so that the `test2` will now do both the validation of `test1` as well as test 2.

Example:-

```
test1(){
//does some processing on getInfo
}
```

save the intial value of getInfo

```
test2(){
//does some processing on getInfo (which was done in test1)
//do the task for test 2
//get the final value of the getInfo and compare with initial test
}
```